# Viewing parameters passed in res.render() in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, rendering

I am trying to push data to a view in node and i try to diplay it.

This is the line in routes.js:

```
res.render('target.ejs', {data:"user"});
```

And this is the `ejs` file:

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
         <p> <h1>{{ data }}</h1> </p>
    </body>


</html>
```

The `user` variable i passed in the `res.render()` is a string.
However, this is what i view when rendering the webpage:

```
{{ data }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display rendered data in ejs file, use this way

```
<h1><%= data %></h1>
```

This should display the string "user". In your routes.js file, If user is a variable and holds some data you should render it like this

```
res.render('target.ejs', {data: user});
```

Comment: Thanks! And the syntax is the same if i want to use the data inside a script? Will 'var random_var = data;' work?

Comment: inside script you use the same way. `var random_var = <%= data %>;`

Answer (score 1):

i don't think ejs has that syntax `{{}}`, its handlebars template syntax and few others like nunjucks have it similar.

You can output data like this `<%= data %>`

their docs: https://ejs.co/#docs